# How to execute an async native process with Kotlin mutliplatform?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I would like to execute a native process with Kotlin native - multiplatform. However, `platform.posix` does not seem to support this functionality.

Is there currently any way to start a specific process (like `echo`), on all or at least on a subset `(mingwx64, linux, ..)` of available platforms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin-native execute command and get the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57123836/kotlin-native-execute-command-and-get-the-output)